# Reverse Engineering Pervasive Database?

Tags: database, reverse-engineering, erd, pervasive

I have a pervasive db which was originally 8x and now I am able to access it using 11x Pervasive. However, I need to get the ERD of that database through reverse engineering. Any suggestions?

I have read that Toad DM version 2 had some support for it but it no longer supports it and not able to find any other modeling tool, please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have DDFs and can create a database within the Pervasive Control Center, you can get the SQL CREATE TABLE statements by right clicking on the table selecting "Edit" then switching to the "SQL View".
I'm not aware of any other ERD tools that explicitly support Pervasive. If you have an ODBC connection to the data, you might be able to use one of the tools that supports ODBC.  Here's a list of tools I found: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools

Answer (score 1):

Look for ODBC drivers.  They are usually pretty fault tolerant when it comes to versions.